# How to realistically show results of high gov spending invested in infrastructure and human capital?

Tags: earth-like, post-apocalypse, near-future, infrastructure

Setting: partially rebuilt post apo world

Technology: comparable to early XXIst century

Afluence: first world equivalent

Mixed economy, semi-authoritarian system, low level of corruption

Resources of whole planet utilized for tiny population (so technological progress slowdown because of lack high number of scientist; low environmental problems; troubles to effectively utilize whole planet)

Effective interest rates for gov investment below 1% (read: if a project needs 100 years to pay itself of, then it is technically speaking worhty)

The challenge is the following. Instead of govs that put top priority towards social spending (because voter loves so) or military (because of real or imagined threat) I'd like to analyse a case of rebuilt post apo world. The priority was rebuilt understood as rebuilding crucial infrastructure and human capital. Needless to say, such aim was clearly achieved, but thanks to innertia it is being continued somewhat beyond average 1st world country from early XXIst century. OK, so what should be built? What should pay itself of in long run, not be cool, but possibly mundane and economic in use? (no deficit generating stadiums or airports, I have this in my country RL)

My ideas:

-Huge hydrodams, as cheapest source of electricity

-electricity grid using HDDC to transfer power from those dams to place when it would be used.

-Humbly looking rail system but rails made of stainless steel (?) (Yes, I know word "monorail", but it is cool, expensive and requires many more people that such planet has)

-concrete roads (?)

-nice mass education system starting in kindergarten

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986)...

Comment: It all depends on the kind of apocalypse, and on the source of your funds. How did you even made money work again in postapo? What is destroyed? What is left? How many people you have? What areas / kinds of human settlements survived? Where does food and clean water comes from? (these are two most important resources!) How you make people who owns food actually sell it? If you don't, what's the point of having money?

Answer (score 1):

- Each child is educated to utilize his or her potential to the fullest. At the same time, there is a clear focus on [STEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_technology,_engineering,_and_mathematics) subjects. So excellent kindergartens and primary schools, and the science teachers get more prestige. Regular science fairs take the role of college sports when it comes to public attention. The various schools get a prominent position on the city map and impressive buildings.
- Trained engineers at decisionmaking positions understand that preventive maintenance is usually cheaper than rebuilding. So when something is built, maintenance funds are budgeted as well. (Unless that was a honest miscalculation how much maintenance is required. Then it will be made up next year, or a deliberate decision was made to let it crumble and to build something else.)
- Almost no private cars on the road, mass transit is used instead. Farmers will have pickup *trucks*, but a clerk or a manager commutes by bus. Roads might well be gravel rather than concrete.
- Long-distance travel is by rail. There are stations in every town, every village.